# Error while using lhttpc from erlang shell

Tags: erlang

When I run following in erlang shell

```
lhttpc:request("http://www.google.co.uk", get, [], infinity).
```

I get this error

```
** exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,
                                   [lhttpc_manager,
                                    {socket,<0.44.0>,"www.google.co.uk",80,false},
                                    infinity]}}
```

I'm a completely new to erlang and only thing I understand from the above is that some `gen_server` module has exited with some error. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on the erlang channel of freenode. I need to run following commands before issuing any requests

```
ssl:start().
lhttpc:start().
```