# erlang exception error: undefined function lhttpc:start/0

Tags: erlang

I am getting a `noproc` exception when I try to call `httpc:request(get, ...)` in a `geturl/1` function

```
** exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,
                                   [httpc_manager,
                                    {request,{request,undefined,<0.54.0>,0,http,
```

In order to fix it, I put in the `start` calls in my `testurl/0` according to this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14553219/58129

```
testurl() ->
    ssl:start(),
    lhttpc:start(),
    geturl("http://www.cnn.com").
```

It fails with this error:

```
so1:testurl().
** exception error: undefined function lhttpc:start/0
     in function  so1:testurl/0 (so1.erl, line 7)
```

I google and I cannot find a module known as `lhttpc`. What is the right way to make `httpc:request` work?

Comment: lhttpc is not part of the Erlang distribution, if you want to use it, you need to download it from [https://github.com/esl/lhttpc](https://github.com/esl/lhttpc) and put it in the VM path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the docs for httpc, you can read:

> When starting the Inets application a manager process for the default profile will be started. The functions in this API that do not explicitly use a profile will access the default profile. A profile keeps track of proxy options, cookies and other options that can be applied to more than one request.
>
> If the scheme https is used the ssl application needs to be started. When https links needs to go through a proxy the CONNECT method extension to HTTP-1.1 is used to establish a tunnel and then the connection is upgraded to TLS, however "TLS upgrade" according to RFC 2817 is not supported.
>
> Also note that pipelining will only be used if the pipeline timeout is set, otherwise persistent connections without pipelining will be used e.i. the client always waits for the previous response before sending the next request.

In short: you have to start inets:

```
application:start(inets).
```

and this is enough for non ssl connections. For https connecitons, you need to also start:

```
application:start(crypto),
application:start(public_key),
application:start(ssl),
application:start(inets).
```

Comment: Hello, this works for me in an Erlang shell but not in a cowboy app. How do I get inets working with cowboy?

Comment: I am not sure why wouldn't it work in Cowboy app. If you send me a link to GitHub repo with failing code and test commands, I might take a stab at fixing it.